# Contact From 7 can do like this?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

example : http://www.thaihappytaxi.com/WebPage/TicketBooking.aspx

Contact From 7 can do like this ?

1.When selected Ticket will show window for select fields for input number of ticket and Add items to **Ticket purchase**

2.How can do send items Added in **Ticket purchase** ?

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried. If you want others to write full code for you, you should consider hiring a freelancer. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Answer (score 0):

I have Reviewed.

Contact form 7 can't work as per your requirements.You can use Gravity Form for the same.